# При запуске ничего не происходит. Игра в угадывание чисел

Tags: java

Знаю что в коде нет ни декомпозиции ни рефакторинга,не судите строго, учусь месяц, если все заработает постараюсь сделать как надо.
В общем код: https://pastebin.com/93FWy3yJ
Почему вообще ничего не происходит при запуске?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код следует _также_ указывать в теле вопроса, а не скриншотами/ссылками, см [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос: Сколько раз выполнится цикл `while`?

```
    int igrokheals = 100;
    int vragheals = 100;
    ...
    while (igrokheals == 0 || vragheals == 0) {
```

Ответ: Нисколько раз.

---

Надо:

```
    while (igrokheals != 0 && vragheals != 0) {
```

Comment: ведь умеете же!